# How to add tabbarcontroller with xib

Tags: ios, xib, tabbarcontroller

First I know how to use XIB to Add TabbarController,

I hope that I can present a tabbarcontroller that is inherit from uitabbarcontroller and has it's own xib file like this:

[image]

so that means I can directly change tabbarItem's image with Interface builder.

Hopefully somebody can teach me how to do it.

Comment: may this help for you .. its working for me when I used xib for tabbar http://bdunagan.com/2009/12/22/uitabbarcontroller-from-a-xib/

Comment: add image so SO users can understand batter. Thanks